# Automatically turn airplane-mode on/off in Windows 8.1 when the Ethernet cable is plugged in/unplugged

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, ethernet, automation

Is there a way to automatically turn airplane-mode on/off in Windows 8.1 when the Ethernet cable is plugged in/unplugged?

According to [this SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/40770/) Windows should be able to work fine with both connections enabled but it's not always the case for me, besides the wired connection is faster.

[A similar, but different, question has been asked for Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/513732/) and the instructions for that work the same way in Windows 8.1 but it was already set to prefer Ethernet over WiFi in there on my computer, so that doesn't solve it for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in feature to do this, but you could achieve what you want with an [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) script with some help from [WMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation).

[Take a look at this script](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/149931-identify-active-network-connection-and-change-dns-server/#entry1070328) that Neutro from [AutoIT Forum](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/) wrote to identify the currently active network connection and change its DNS settings:

```autoit
#requireadmin
#include <Array.au3>

$wbemFlagReturnImmediately = 0x10
$wbemFlagForwardOnly = 0x20
$colItems = ""
$query = ""

Local $active_netword_cards[1]
Local $network_cards_to_setup[1]

$active_netword_cards[0]=""
$network_cards_to_setup[0]=""

;getting a list of all network cards
$objWMIService = ObjGet("winmgmts:\\localhost\root\CIMV2")
$colItems = $objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter", "WQL", _
                                          $wbemFlagReturnImmediately + $wbemFlagForwardOnly)

If IsObj($colItems) then
   For $objItem In $colItems
      if $objItem.NetConnectionStatus == "2" OR $objItem.NetConnectionStatus == "9" Then ;if the network connection is active, we add the index of the network card and the connection name to $active_netword_cards array
         _arrayAdd($active_netword_cards, $objItem.Index)
         _arrayAdd($active_netword_cards, $objItem.NetConnectionID)
      endif
   Next
Endif

;getting settings from all network cards in the array $active_netword_cards
for $i = 1 to UBound($active_netword_cards) - 1 step 2
   $query = $objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE Index = " & $active_netword_cards[$i], "WQL", _
                                          $wbemFlagReturnImmediately + $wbemFlagForwardOnly)

   For $objItem In $query
   if $objItem.DHCPEnabled == "False" Then _arrayAdd($network_cards_to_setup, $active_netword_cards[$i+1]) ;if DHCP is disabled, we add the network card name in the $network_cards_to_setup array
   next
Next

;setting up primary DNS server of all network cards in the $network_cards_to_setup array
;DNS server used in this example is 10.10.2.45

for $i = 1 to UBound($network_cards_to_setup) - 1 step 1
   Runwait('netsh interface IP ADD DNS "'& $network_cards_to_setup[$i] &'" 10.10.2.45 index=1')
Next
```

You can modify the script to loop at pre-determined intervals and whenever an Ethernet connection is detected in `$active_netword_cards`, you could run [this PowerShell command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20366841/1768141) from within the AutoIT script